# Setting the width and height of a JComponent as instance variables

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a problem with setting the width and height of a component as instance variables (in the subclass of the component). If I call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` in the constructor (which is always zero), the values are different from calling the same methods in `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Can someone please explain why this is happening and how can I set the width and height of the component as instance variables. Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MyComponent extends JComponent
{
    // Instance variables.
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public MyComponent()
    {
        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();
        System.out.println(width+","+height);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        // Local variables.
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        System.out.println(width+","+height);
    }

}
```

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ComponentTester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        MyComponent component = new MyComponent();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(350, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(component);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your component's width and height is not set until rendered.

Comment: Tanks.... so how can I set the width and height as instance variables.

Comment: You can use `setPreferedSize`, or use a layoutmanager which automatically packs the component.

Comment: Tanks Pphoenix .. I called the getWidth() and getHeight() in the paintComponent method to set the instance variables and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a components size is up to the component. So in constructor the default size is 0. Later on if you add the component into a layout manager (like you did when adding your component to the frame which has a default layout manager) it will set the size according to preferred/minimum/maximum this - which is 0/0 to max-int by default. So layout manager will resize the component to the size of the frame.

There is no need to store the size in a local copy as getWidth()/Height() will read the size from a local copy in the component class.